# Is it possible to retain prop type information when importing Svelte components into TypeScript files?

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

*EDIT: This turns out to be caused by a known issue with a fix being worked on: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1256*

*This only happens if you are using the Svelte VS Code extension with TypeScript support enabled and also have `"jsx": "react"` or similar set in your `tsconfig.json`, likely because you're also using React in the project.*

I have a basic typed Svelte component in `Hello.svelte` that takes a single prop like this:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  export let value: string;
</script>

<div>Hello, {value}</div>
```

I then import it and mount it into the DOM from TypeScript using a file like this:

```
import Hello from './Hello.svelte';

const initHello = () => {
  const node = document.getElementById('content')!;
  new Hello({
    target: node,
    // \/ I would like this to throw a type error since the required `value` prop is missing
    props: {},
  });
}
```

As I mention in the comment above, the type information of `Hello`'s props is lost when importing it into TypeScript.  None of my VS Code plugins - TypeScript, Svelte, or otherwise - complain and `svelte-check` doesn't seem to care either (although I'm not familiar with that tool).

Is there any way that I can make this boundary typed?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to create generic typed functions to render Svelte components like this:

```
function renderSvelte<P extends Record<string, any>>(
  Comp: TypedSvelteComponentConstructor<P>,
  props: P,
) {
 // ...
}
```

However, whenever I import Svelte components from TypeScript, the type resolves as a non-generic `SvelteComponent` rather than `TypedSvelteComponent` with accurate prop info.

I'd be OK with a method of defining the component props in a third location and importing them from both the Svelte component and the TypeScript file, although that wouldn't be as good as true auto-detection when importing the Svelte file into TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

To have better IDE support, you need to activate the TypeScript plugin of the [Svelte for VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) by setting `svelte.enable-ts-plugin` to `true` - if you are using another editor, I'm not sure how to best integrate the TypeScript plugin. What the plugin does is to provide better intellisense for Svelte files used within TypeScript files - including showing an error when you missed a required property. Note that there is currently a limitation when using React/JSX in the same project, in this case the plugin does nothing: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1256

To have better support when checking this through the CLI, use `svelte-check` version 2 and call it providing the path to your `tsconfig.json` like this: `svelte-check --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json` (assuming you run this from the project root and your tsconfig is at the root). When doing this, `svelte-check` will take care of checking TypeScript files, too, while providing better support for Svelte files used in TypeScript files. If you don't add the `--tsconfig` option, `svelte-check` will only check Svelte files and therefore you are missing out on the diagnostics you desire.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this info.  I do have the `svelte.enable-ts-plugin` config option enable and typechecking is working perfectly within `.svelte files`.  Unfortunately, when importing `.svelte` files into TypeScript, type information still seems to not be preserved; the example I posted in my question still throws no type errors.

My `svelte-check` now logs thousands of errors when using the `--tsconfig` flag - ty for that.   However, I'm unable to tell if this particular type error exists in the output.

Comment: About the plugin: Could you share a minimum reproducible and open an issue at https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues ? Then I'll look into it. About `svelte-check`: If there are false positives or there's something else that feels wrong also feel free to open issue at https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues . Thanks!

Comment: Aha - I did a bit more digging and it seems that this is a known issue, and happily a fix is being worked on!  https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/1256

I should have checked for that before posting here.  Would you recommend I edit the question or add another answer noting this information?

Comment: I updated my answer to add a note about the limitation. It might also be the reason why you see many errors when running `svelte-check` if the tsconfig also contains the React/JSX files. You could try to create a separate tsconfig which excludes the React/JSX files and run `svelte-check` using that one. I think it would be good to add this information to your question.